# What comes after "can"?

Tags: grammar

I had a test and there was a question I'm arguing about its answer with my brother. Question is what comes after "can" (or fill in the blank:D)

Question: I'm sure she'll do whatever she can ...

Possible choices:

1. to help
2. help

Which one is the answer? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: Adding strategic punctuation makes the second choice work as well.  `I'm sure she'll do whatever. She can help.`  `I'm sure she'll do.  Whatever, she can help.`  Perhaps that's where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm sure she'll do whatever she can to help.

This is correct. She'll do "whatever she can", but only those things that will help (or with the purpose of helping).

> I'm sure she'll do whatever she can help.

This is incorrect - grammatically, it is saying she'll help the things she's doing, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The "to help" after "can" is an infinitive of purpose meaning "in order to help".

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence, *she can* is a relative clause inserted to modify *whatever*.  The essence of the sentence is really saying:

> She'll do whatever to help.

*she can* further clarifies the *whatever*, limiting the scope of the whatever to those things which she has the ability to do.  Another more substantial relative clause can be used to better illustrate the modularity of them:

> She'll do whatever *that's contained in the list given to her by the doctor* to help.

The test question is trying to trick you by making you think of the also-correct sentence "she can help," but it's the wrong answer.